# Calling function from Ext JS 4 combo box listeners

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am having problems in calling the custom function from combo box listeners in Ext JS 4.
I have set up combo box listeners like below.

```
listeners:{
    select:{
        fn:function(combo, value) {
            this.test;
        }
    }
}
```

And my custom function is that I have created after the closing of

```
 this.callParent(arguments);
```

My custom function is

```
  test: function(){
        alert('test');
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your scoping is wrong, the `this` in your select function refers to your combo, and probably no to your object your test function is on. Also if you call a function you need your braces around it: `this.test()`

probably better the following way:

```
initComponent: function() {  
    var me = this;
    me.items = [//... 
    {
       xtype: 'boxselect',
       //props...
       listeners: {
           select:{
               fn:function(combo, value) {
                   this.test(); // this will now be the this variable that you give to your scope.
                   //Or simply: me.test();
               }
           },
           scope: me
       }
    }
    //...
    ];

    me.callParent();
}
```

You might want to post some more code because we need to know the scope of your test function and the scope of your combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code

```
  initComponent: function() {           
            this.items = [
            {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    padding: '5 5 0 5',
                    autoScroll:true,
                    border: false,
                    style: 'background-color: #fff;',
                      items: [
                      {
                            xtype:'fieldset',

                        columnWidth: 0.5,
                        id:'adfieldset',
                        title: 'Ad Details',
                        collapsible: true,
                        defaultType: 'textfield',
                        defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
                        layout: 'anchor',

                          items: [
                          {
                                    xtype : 'boxselect',
                                    store : 'product.CategoryComboBox',
                                    name: 'category[]',
                                    id:'category',
                                    displayField: 'name',
                                    valueField: 'idProductCategory',
                                    multiSelect : false,
                                    fieldLabel: 'Category',
                                    //allowBlank: false,
                                    allowQueryAll : false,
                                    multiSelect : true,
                                    forceSelection : true,
                                    typeAhead: true,
                                    triggerAction: 'all',
                                    delimiter : ',',
                                    width: 300,
                                    queryMode:'local',


                                    listeners:{select:{fn:function(combo, value) {
                                       this.test;
```

Comment: The code is not complete, but I'm very sure it is a scoping issue as my answer below.

Comment: Then is there  a way to solve the scope issue.PLease let me know.

Comment: I've posted a solution, that should work, have you tried it atleast?